# WordPress registered setting won't save

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add a *Shortlink Domain* setting to the *Optional* section of WordPress's *Permalinks* Settings page. For some reason, the value is not saving to the database. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I'm having a hard time figuring it out.

```
function urb_admin_init_shortlink_domain()
{
    $option_group = 'optional'; // not sure what to put here
    $option_name = 'shortlink_domain';
    $sanitiaze_callback = ''; // for validation

    register_setting( $option_group, $option_name, $sanitize_callback );


    $id = 'shortlink_domain';
    $title = 'Shortlink Domain';
    $callback = 'urb_shortlink_domain';
    $page = 'permalink';
    $section = 'optional';
    $args = '';

    add_settings_field( $id, $title, $callback, $page, $section, $args );
}

function urb_shortlink_domain()
{

    $option = 'shortlink_domain';
    echo '<input type="text" name="' . $option . '" id="' . $option . '" value="' . get_option( $option ) . '" class="regular-text ltr" />';
}

function urb_get_shortlink( $shortlink, $id = 0, $context = null, $allow_slugs = null )
{
    global $post;

    return get_option('shortlink_domain') . $post->ID;
}
```

I'm not sure what to put for `$option_group` in `urb_admin_init_shortlink_domain()`. I tried `permalink`, `optional`, `default`, `urb_shortlink_domain`.

I tried reordering all of the functions and made sure to visit the Permalinks page each time.